# “Canberra is to the south of Sydney” vs “Canberra is to Sydney’s south”

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, phrase-choice, sentence-choice

Are these sentences interchangeable?

- “Canberra is to the south of Sydney.”
- “Canberra is to Sydney’s south.”

  I know that the structure in the former is correct, but I wonder if I can use the latter to mean the same thing. I am not sure if it is correct or not. I feel like the latter might be wrong, but I think it is more likely that it is correct. What I mean is that Canberra lies to the south of Sydney.

Comment: The latter is not idiomatic.

Comment: @user100323, not true: depends on context. E.G., "What cites are around Sydney?" "“Canberra is to Sydney’s south, and Newcastle is to it's north.” (Not to mention Wagga Wagga!!)